# How to call Catch if boolean value is false or my condition not return any values?

Tags: c#

Am just wondering how to workaround my scenario,here is my code

```
 try
            {
                bool b;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    #region donloadfiles
                    if (b = file.Contains(story))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            logger.Info("calling xml creation Method");
                            baseMeta(story, XML);
                            logger.Info("XML created");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { logger.Error(ex.Message); throw; }

                        logger.Info("calling Download Method");
                        Download(file, story, xml, program);
                        logger.Info("Download Method processed successfully");
                    }
                    #endregion
                }


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            { logger.Error(ex.Message); throw; }
```

As promised,here is my main method contains try catch block

```
 try
            {

                //update the status here in DB
               Status = "Closed";
               Update(status);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Status = "Failed";
                Update(status);
                break;
            }
```

i have directory "for eg:C:\" my getlist method grab all the record and pass it to my foreach loop "foreach (string file in files)" then i have a condition

if (b = file.Contains(story)) to check any of my file have the name "story" then do some logic inside.this thing works good.

Now what am trying to do is,if none of the files are matching then i have to forcefully call the catch and throw to the main catch,am doing some logic update in my main catch.

Someone please advice me how can i workaround this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not depend on catch. Because by performance its very poor. CLR has to do alot more job in raising an exception and handling/catching it. So instead change your logic with out depending on the catch.

If you still wish to go this way, then use throw(..) statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am trying to do is,if none of the files are matching then i have
>   to forcefully call the catch and throw to the main catch,am doing some
>   logic update in my main catch.

```
bool anyMatch = false;

foreach (.....)
{
      if (b = file.Contains(story))
         anyMatch = true;
}

if(!anyMatch)
    throw ... //this will be caught by main catch
```

Keep a bool variable outside foreach loop. Set it to true if any file matches. if it is false at the end of foreach loop throw exception

Answer (score 1):

Usher, using exceptions to manage process flow is a BAD idea!
Exceptions are there to manage errors, and not to handle expected conditions in your code's execution.

A much better way (in the long run:trust me on this) would be to return some value out of your method when none of the files match instead of throwing an exception.

Something like:

```
  #region donloadfiles
                    if (b = file.Contains(story))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            logger.Info("calling xml creation Method");
                            baseMeta(story, XML);
                            logger.Info("XML created");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        { logger.Error(ex.Message); throw; }

                        logger.Info("calling Download Method");
                        Download(file, story, xml, program);
                        logger.Info("Download Method processed successfully");
                    }

else return "no matches found";
                        #endregion
```

and handle the process from there once you've gotten the "no matches found" value in the place that called this method.

Comment: @casllisto,i Suppose to strictly follow your idea and "zenwalker"but my scenairo is, if no files are matched then i stop the process and return to my main menu,in the main menu i have try catch block,in the catch block i update my db about the file status is "Failed to download the file" am not sure is that make sense or not but if guys provide me some alternate way to proceed much appreciated i will update the OP with my main catch block also.

Comment: @castllisto,can you please advice me,after post my main catch method,what am doing is make sense ? or still i should totally avoid to call the catch ? Thanks in Advance